# How to extract data particular from large string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a large string below the example of a large string

`2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234985 E:72.858528 4 km/h 275.15 -0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234987 E:72.858437 4 km/h 275.15 -8.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:32 N:21.234989 E:72.858452 0 km/h 270.92 -6.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:33 N:21.234995 E:72.858482 0 km/h 269.48 -3.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:34 N:21.234997 E:72.858505 0 km/h 275.53 -1.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:35 N:21.234999 E:72.858521 0 km/h 276.25 0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000`

I need to extract N and E from every line and i have two lists like nList and eList every N element is added to nList and every E element is added into eList.

Is it possible in Flutter or Dart?

Can you have any idea about it?

Here is the attachment of `.txt` file for reference...
[String File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d6cpPHec7d1ozaU7dLdTEvL2e2czWhm8/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression pattern `r"N:([0-9.]+) E:([0-9.]+)"` matches both `N` and `E` values in each line after you splited your string with `\n` character:

```
void main() {
  String largeString =
      "2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234985 E:72.858528 4 km/h 275.15 -0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000\n2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234987 E:72.858437 4 km/h 275.15 -8.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000\n2023/03/11 11:14:32 N:21.234989 E:72.858452 0 km/h 270.92 -6.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000\n2023/03/11 11:14:33 N:21.234995 E:72.858482 0 km/h 269.48 -3.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000\n2023/03/11 11:14:34 N:21.234997 E:72.858505 0 km/h 275.53 -1.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000\n2023/03/11 11:14:35 N:21.234999 E:72.858521 0 km/h 276.25 0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000";
  List<String> lines = largeString.split("\n");
  List<String> nList = [];
  List<String> eList = [];

  for (String line in lines) {
    RegExp regExp = RegExp(r"N:([0-9.]+) E:([0-9.]+)");
    RegExpMatch? match = regExp.firstMatch(line);
    if (match != null) {
      String n = match.group(1)!;
      String e = match.group(2)!;
      nList.add(n);
      eList.add(e);
    }
    print(eList);
    print(nList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current format, you can use this code as a temporary solution.
Because your data looks like space separated records with no table headers.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main(List<String> args) {
  final lines = const LineSplitter().convert(_data);
  final list = <({num e, num n})>[];
  for (final line in lines) {
    final parts = line.split(' ');
    num e = 0;
    num n = 0;
    for (final part in parts) {
      if (part.startsWith('N:')) {
        n = num.parse(part.substring(2));
      } else if (part.startsWith('E:')) {
        e = num.parse(part.substring(2));
      }
    }

    final value = (e: e, n: n);
    list.add(value);
  }

  print(list.join('\n'));
}

const _data = '''
2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234985 E:72.858528 4 km/h 275.15 -0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234987 E:72.858437 4 km/h 275.15 -8.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:32 N:21.234989 E:72.858452 0 km/h 270.92 -6.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:33 N:21.234995 E:72.858482 0 km/h 269.48 -3.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:34 N:21.234997 E:72.858505 0 km/h 275.53 -1.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:35 N:21.234999 E:72.858521 0 km/h 276.25 0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:36 N:21.234997 E:72.858528 0 km/h 275.06 2.40  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:37 N:21.234997 E:72.858536 0 km/h 273.31 3.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:38 N:21.235003 E:72.858543 0 km/h 274.19 4.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:39 N:21.235003 E:72.858543 0 km/h 289.47 4.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:40 N:21.235004 E:72.858543 0 km/h 282.73 5.80  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:41 N:21.235003 E:72.858551 0 km/h 283.26 6.70  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:42 N:21.235010 E:72.858582 0 km/h 276.49 9.40  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:43 N:21.235012 E:72.858589 0 km/h 289.28 10.40  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:44 N:21.235020 E:72.858612 0 km/h 290.78 13.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:45 N:21.235022 E:72.858635 0 km/h 293.79 16.30  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:46 N:21.235023 E:72.858635 0 km/h 289.47 16.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:47 N:21.235025 E:72.858635 0 km/h 286.46 17.80  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:48 N:21.235027 E:72.858643 0 km/h 283.10 18.30  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:49 N:21.235029 E:72.858643 0 km/h 286.21 19.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:50 N:21.235029 E:72.858643 0 km/h 283.94 21.00  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:51 N:21.235041 E:72.858658 0 km/h 281.41 21.80  8 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:52 N:21.235041 E:72.858650 0 km/h 306.67 22.30  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:53 N:21.235039 E:72.858650 0 km/h 294.09 22.80  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000''';
```

Output:

```
(e: 72.858528, n: 21.234985)
(e: 72.858437, n: 21.234987)
(e: 72.858452, n: 21.234989)
(e: 72.858482, n: 21.234995)
(e: 72.858505, n: 21.234997)
(e: 72.858521, n: 21.234999)
(e: 72.858528, n: 21.234997)
(e: 72.858536, n: 21.234997)
(e: 72.858543, n: 21.235003)
(e: 72.858543, n: 21.235003)
(e: 72.858543, n: 21.235004)
(e: 72.858551, n: 21.235003)
(e: 72.858582, n: 21.23501)
(e: 72.858589, n: 21.235012)
(e: 72.858612, n: 21.23502)
(e: 72.858635, n: 21.235022)
(e: 72.858635, n: 21.235023)
(e: 72.858635, n: 21.235025)
(e: 72.858643, n: 21.235027)
(e: 72.858643, n: 21.235029)
(e: 72.858643, n: 21.235029)
(e: 72.858658, n: 21.235041)
(e: 72.85865, n: 21.235041)
(e: 72.85865, n: 21.235039)
```

Another way.

```dart
import 'package:fast_csv/fast_csv_ex.dart' as fast_csv_ex;

void main(List<String> args) {
  final rows = fast_csv_ex.parse(_source, separator: ' ');
  for (final row in rows) {
    final map = Map.fromEntries(row
        .where((e) => e.length > 3 && e[1] == ':')
        .map((e) => MapEntry(e[0], e.substring(2))));
    final n = map['N'];
    final e = map['E'];
    print('E:$e, N:$n');
    print(map);
  }
}

const _source = '''
2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234985 E:72.858528 4 km/h 275.15 -0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234987 E:72.858437 4 km/h 275.15 -8.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
2023/03/11 11:14:32 N:21.234989 E:72.858452 0 km/h 270.92 -6.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000''';
```

Output:

```
E:72.858437, N:21.234987
{N: 21.234987, E: 72.858437, x: +0.000, y: +0.000, z: +0.000}
E:72.858452, N:21.234989
{N: 21.234989, E: 72.858452, x: +0.000, y: +0.000, z: +0.000}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`:

```dart
void main() {
  String largeString = '''
      2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234985 E:72.858528 4 km/h 275.15 -0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
      2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234987 E:72.858437 4 km/h 275.15 -8.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
      2023/03/11 11:14:32 N:21.234989 E:72.858452 0 km/h 270.92 -6.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
      2023/03/11 11:14:33 N:21.234995 E:72.858482 0 km/h 269.48 -3.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
      2023/03/11 11:14:34 N:21.234997 E:72.858505 0 km/h 275.53 -1.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
      2023/03/11 11:14:35 N:21.234999 E:72.858521 0 km/h 276.25 0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000
  ''';

  final nList = <String>[];
  final eList = <String>[];

  final regex = RegExp(r'N:(\S+) E:(\S+)');

  regex.allMatches(largeString).forEach((match) {
    nList.add(match.group(1)!);
    eList.add(match.group(2)!);
  });

  print('N List: $nList');
  print('E List: $eList');
}
```

Output:

```
N List: [21.234985, 21.234987, 21.234989, 21.234995, 21.234997, 21.234999]
E List: [72.858528, 72.858437, 72.858452, 72.858482, 72.858505, 72.858521]
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is here

simple regexp is
`(N:[\d.]{1,}[\s]{1}E:[\d.]{1,}[\s]{1})`

```
void main() {
  var texts  =
      "2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234985 E:72.858528 4 km/h 275.15 -0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:30 N:21.234987 E:72.858437 4 km/h 275.15 -8.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:32 N:21.234989 E:72.858452 0 km/h 270.92 -6.90  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:33 N:21.234995 E:72.858482 0 km/h 269.48 -3.60  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:34 N:21.234997 E:72.858505 0 km/h 275.53 -1.20  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000 2023/03/11 11:14:35 N:21.234999 E:72.858521 0 km/h 276.25 0.50  9 x:+0.000 y:+0.000 z:+0.000";
    //Declaring a RegExp object with a pattern that matches sequences of digits
    RegExp reg1 = RegExp(r'(N:[\d.]{1,}[\s]{1}E:[\d.]{1,}[\s]{1})');
    RegExp cord = RegExp(r'([\d.]{1,}[\s]{1})');
    //Iterating over the matches returned from allMatches
    Iterable allMatches = reg1.allMatches(texts);
    List N = [],E=[];
    allMatches.forEach((match) {
        print(texts.substring(match.start, match.end));
        Iterable matchc = cord.allMatches(texts.substring(match.start, match.end));
        var Ns = matchc.toList()[0];
        var Es = matchc.toList()[1];
        N.add(texts.substring(match.start, match.end).substring(Ns.start,Ns.end));
        E.add(texts.substring(match.start, match.end).substring(Es.start,Es.end));
         print(texts.substring(match.start, match.end).substring(Ns.start,Ns.end));
         print(texts.substring(match.start, match.end).substring(Es.start,Es.end));
    });
}
```

also you can test in emulator

[https://dartpad.dev/](https://dartpad.dev/?)